# UIImagePickerController custom overlay and tap-to-focus

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to display a tap-to-focus blue box when a custom overlay is used in a UIImagePickerView and when showsCameraControl attribute is set to FALSE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modal camera view already supports touch-to-focus. You need to make your overlay view "transparent" to touches.

Subclass a UIView as OverlayView and add something like this. In my overlay view I have two buttons, which should of course not be transparent for touching.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(infoButton.frame, point) || CGRectContainsPoint(snapButton.frame, point)) {
        // touched button
        return YES; 
    }

    return NO;
}
```

There are probably other and more elegant ways to do this.
I think you would also have to add the little "focus rectangle" on your view programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom button for that with alpha value zero. And with text that you want to display